# Convert specific types of values in an object to another type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Hi I want to declare a type from another type, e.g.

```js
// from this type
type Source = {
  id: string
  name: string
  price: Decimal
  createdAt: Date
}

// want to create this type
// Decimal and Date types are converted to string while other fields are kept untouched
type Destination = {
  id: string
  name: string
  price: string
  createdAt: string
}

// It is desired to declare the destination type with some generics:
type Destination = SomeGenerics<Source>;
```

Is it possible using [TypeScript type manipulation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html)?

Context: After `JSON.stringify` an object and `JSON.parse`, the fields with type Decimal or Date are converted into string. I want to create a type for the resulting object in the most effortless way, since there are many source types and declaring all the destination types by hand is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
type JsonConverter<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {[key in keyof T]: ToStringIfExtends<T[key], Date | Decimal>}

type ToStringIfExtends<K, E> = K extends E ? string : K
```

Comment: It works, thanks! By the way I found that we must convert these types recursively... since in some cases date fields are in nested objects. Can we possibly achieve that?